# Quarkus with custom main method

Tags: quarkus

Is it possible to provide a custom `main(String[] args)` method for a Quarkus application? Or is there any other way to access the command line arguments?

The use case would be to build a native image to be used as a command line tool.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is now officially supported :) https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle

```
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain;
import io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus;

@QuarkusMain  
public class Main {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println("Running main method");
        Quarkus.run(args); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Currently Quarkus doesn't support this use case, however it is definitely on the roadmap, see: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/284

**Update**

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61665893/2504224 for the supported way of doing this